# Why don't Sci-fi stories draw energy directly from their stars using wormholes/FTL devices?

Tags: stars, power-sources, wormholes

Science fiction is full of devices allowing people to open portals to other worlds, teleport, open wormholes, etc. but there are only subtle discussions about tapping into the sun or other stars with the same technology, usually as a weapon (often teleporting an enemy into said star).

Civilizations spend vast amounts of time generating fusion, collecting solar radiation, manufacturing antimatter and the like. If your civilization has an FTL device allowing you to essentially open portals, then why don't they open tiny portals into stars and vent off some of the superheated material to power spaceships, direct outward as plasma weapons, or even run planetary power grids, etc? Why not even use this as the thruster for a spaceship as they travel with conventional engines? A big enough portal could move planets. I don't know if this would work, but draining the core of a star might extend the life of the star by cooling the fusion or venting the heavy elements that speed fusion, not to mention generating billions of tons of matter for any project.

**What is stopping all these sci-fi worlds with teleporters from tapping the virtually unlimited power source instead of harvesting or manufacturing expensive, complex fuels?**

Is it containment? processing the energy into a useful form? Too much, too fast?  If using the portals took insane energy levels to open, they wouldn't be practical to move ships and people. Hard science answers would be good, but I'm not tagging it as such because all answers are welcome (especially since portals are already handwaving).

Comment: This might be too broad, considering all the sci-fi implementations of these technologies.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't set hard science as a tag, as it would be impossible to answer a question about handwavium devices.  It seems that you are questioning the motives behind the narrative decision-making of an unspecified set of writers.  Any answers are going to be speculative or limited to a single example.  Here's a hint though - think about why authors don't write about characters who can solve all of their problems effortlessly.

Comment: You might be interested in "Stranger Suns", which uses this premise.  The first part of the book is available on the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v65n05_1991-01#page/n9/mode/2up

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Actually I was curious as to if there was a compelling physics reason I wasn't aware of that this isn't used as a universal mechanism. "because it's too easy" might be the legitimate answer.

Comment: This site is for answering world building questions, not discussing established franchises. especially not in broad strokes like "why doesn't X show up in all of fiction". Given that there *are* examples of X here, the question is at the very least invalid. Reading it as a broad "why doesn't it happen often" is going to be opinion based at best. Some fiction just doesn't want to deal with explaining this. Or doesn't want to allow access to such powers. If it *otherwise make sense* for a given universe to have a feature but it doesn't, this might be a better question for [scifi.se].

Comment: Chicken-and-egg problem, I’d say. You must have solved your energy problem to open a portal. All of our current theories say that you need either some exotic matter/energy (not delivered by the Sun) or more energy than our Sun can deliver. Once you’ve solve it, you don’t care about that tiny amount of non-exotic energy of the Sun.

Comment: The author stops them.

Comment: Because the authors of those science-fiction works didn't think of it. Though David Langford's *The Space Eater* does come close. Sorry, it's all to simple, purely a failure of imagination. The poor blighters can't think of everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not unknown in SciFi to use such power sources. *Star Trek* canon states Romulan spaceships are powered using a controlled singularity.

However...

**Heat**

And just to make things interesting... the sun is hot. Now, to be fair, theoretically nuclear fusion is hot, so the temperatures shouldn't be any more difficult to control. But I'm throwing it out there because, whatever tech is being used to open the portals in the first place... well... the sun's hot.  Maybe this one isn't that big a' deal... so I got it out of the way first.

**Gravity**

The gravity of a sun is non-trivial. Opening a portal that deep into a gravity well would have... consequences.  That portal would let energy through, but it would also want so suck the ship it's powering into the star. Dealing with the gravitic shear would be impressive.

**Pressure**

Just as gravity is trying to suck your ship through the portal, the sun, itself, is trying to push itself through.  Think "ew! Popping a zit!" on the scale of gazillions of megapascals.  So, now we have a shell around the portal that's trying to keep the ship from being crushed like the proverbial beer can from gravity and popping like ants on a hot plate from the outward pressure.

**Motion**

The star is in motion. The ship is in motion. Those two motions aren't usually compatible. Some authors have used this in their stories (Larry Niven's *Ringworld* stories come to mind), and it's an issue you'd need to deal with. As the ship changes relative-motion vectors with the star the energy being pumped through the portal would change and the portal itself would have problems. If you're going to be real about this, the stream of energy would be anything but constant — and motion is one of the reasons why.

**Activists**

Just to reflect the "real world..." *activists!* "Turn and run! Not my sun!" Whole civilizations may protest the use of their sun to power your spaceships. Who cares if you're reducing the life of the star by a measly twenty minutes? "You've gone too far! Not my star!"

Comment: Would gravity be a significant factor if you were taking matter from the very core of the sun? Shouldn't the gravity cancel there? Doesn't fix heat, pressure (figured those could be fixed by minimizing the time a portal was open). I hadn't considered motion, it could be a real issue (although I could think of ways this could compensate for some issues...) If you know the effects of core matter loss on stellar life, I'd love to know them (does cooling a star by venting core material slow fusion and extend the life of the star?). I like this one. Thanks!

Comment: @DWKraus At the infinitely small point at the center, yes, but anything outside that, no. I was challenged about this years ago (I wish I could find the link, I did quite an analysis to prove myself wrong because I believed as you do). Worse, as gravity decreases (which isn't linear), pressure increases, until you get to that infinitely small point. Even if that point were big enough for a portal, there's nothing there but a bit of plasma, so there's nothing practical to mine. We'd need a master of solar physics to prove it, but I suspect the majority of the useful energy is near the surface.

Comment: If you find it, let me know how big an area there is at the core with negligible gravity. Otherwise this might be what I was looking for.

Comment: @DWKraus The density is 150x that of water according to Wikipedia, and scales as r^3. If you're off-core by 10km, the gravity is under 1N per kg of ship. The pressure is more than 10^16 Pa though so I hope your ship had insurance.

Comment: It'd be a great WMD though https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0ldO87Pprc

Comment: STAR LIVES MATTER!!!

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak for what goes through science-fiction authors' heads, and I can't really help you find out why an author made the decisions they did. What I can do is give a handful of ideas for a world in which this doesn't happen, and why it might not happen.

---

- Portals can only open or close in vacuum.

While objects can pass through a pair of linked portals once they're open, the process of opening them requires as little molecular interference as possible, as turbulence or collisions on either end will disperse the connection. Stars have a lot of potential sources of interference. (Similarly, such an explanation also prevents "portal cutting"; if there's a significant amount of matter passing through, you can't close a portal, so be careful opening one up inside an octillion tons of matter!)

- You need structures at *both* ends of your intended connection to open a portal.

Generally speaking, it is somewhat difficult to make a ship capable of swimming through super-dense plasma hotter than the melting point of basically any known material.

- Portal structures cannot handle the conditions of having uncontained plasma surge through them.

Perhaps the structure that contains a portal on the opener's end has temperature-sensitive functionality, or simply has to be made of materials that melt at less than 10,000 K. I would imagine that a structure linking two points in space needs to also resist vibrations, else things might get distorted or ripped open as they come through; a high-pressure jet might not be safe to handle without exceeding safety tolerances.

- Portals conserve energy in some way.

Moving a spaceship from one point far from any gravity well to some other similar point without changing its velocity involves a very small change in the ship's total energy, which you need to put into the portal structure. Teleporting someone down to a planet from a ship in orbit subtracts their gravitational potential energy, so it conveniently goes back into your portal system to be used for the return trip.

It takes a staggering amount of energy, meanwhile, to drag huge amounts of matter all the way out of the gravity well of a star. Unless you're able to drop some asteroids in (and your power systems can handle the surge) to build up enough energy, you're not going to be getting much plasma out in return.

Comment: On your last point, it might be interesting to compare the depth of a star's energy well to the energy density of stellar material.

Comment: @parasoup
"what goes through science-fiction authors' heads"
Spot on.
A lot of people get bogged down in the details of certain things to the point of forgetting that there is a story the the author is trying to tell.
Imagine arguing about Hamlet's age and totally forgetting anything about the play.
That's what a lot of these discussion boil down to.

Comment: @Seallussus I was talking more about how the asker brought up why *other* sci-fi worlds don't do something, and *that's* the whim of the author. I'm not qualified to answer that kind of question, so I tried to answer from an in-setting perspective instead. I don't think I could endorse "don't worry about the details" in this context.

Comment: @BBeast I don't quite have the time to dig into plasma physics to figure out internal thermal energy, but my barest back-of-envelope calculations suggest that the energy required to bring matter from the Sun's surface to infinity is *probably* greater than that matter's heat energy but less than what you'd get from fusing it — admittedly, it'll be mostly protons, which are really hard to fuse. Perhaps pulling mass from the star's center makes this cheaper, but I'd be impressed by a portal system that can pinpoint a target through half a million kilometers of plasma.

Comment: A back-of-the-envelope like that is good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Charlie Stross Novel *Glasshouse*, there is a weapon that essentially opens a tiny wormhole into a star for very short amount of time. It even exists in handgun form (though IIRC it's more of a directed explosion than a shot).

The *Singularity Sky* 'verse by the same author also features wormholes and FTL, but since black holes can also be manufactured (as a component of some FTL drives) and managed these are used as power source (via hawking radiation I think), so there's no need to directly harness a sun. The possibility to use the FTL technology to manipulate a star is used to interesting effect in *Iron Sunrise* (Same 'verse):

> In this Universe, FTL implies time travel and the space nazis have the far future version of a star travel back into itself, causing an instant supernova because of the sudden mass influx.

In Iain M. Banks Culture novels, such a weapon does *not* appear AFAIR - instead, warships use their teleporting ("Displacement") ability (in Universe explained with wormholes) to position missiles in good tactical position, or to teleport Antimatter directly into or onto the enemy.

It's hard to answer why authors write the way they do. My pet theory is that many stories are not written as an exploration of more or less fictional possibilities, but start with certain tropes the author thinks are cool or helpful to tell his story, and the worldbuilding walks backward from that.